# how do i stop a spinnerList from repeating in flash builder?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, spinner, mxml, repeat

i have a spinner list that just keeps scrolling how do stop it from repeating data?

```
<s:SpinnerListContainer id="branchSpinner" width="100%" >
    <s:SpinnerList id="branchData" width="100%" height="100%" labelField="data" selectedIndex="1" > 
        <s:ArrayList >
            <fx:Object id="b1" data="branch 1"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object id="b2" data="branch 2"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object id="b3" data="branch 3"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object id="b4" data="branch 4"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object id="b5" data="branch 5"></fx:Object>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:SpinnerList>
</s:SpinnerListContainer>
```

i looked for a property like repeat data or something but I could never find it. any help would be much appreciated Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you are wanting to remove the revolution, where the list head and tail match up and can be scrolled through again.

If so, this can be achieved by changing the **wrapElements** property to false. *(When using the Flex 4.6 SDK).*

For example:

```
<s:SpinnerList change="myEvent(event)" labelField="data" selectedIndex="2" wrapElements="false">
    <s:ArrayList>
        <fx:Object data="10"></fx:Object>
        <fx:Object data="12"></fx:Object>
        <fx:Object data="16"></fx:Object>
        <fx:Object data="20"></fx:Object>
        <fx:Object data="22"></fx:Object>
        <fx:Object data="24"></fx:Object>
        <fx:Object data="28"></fx:Object>
        <fx:Object data="32"></fx:Object>
        <fx:Object data="36"></fx:Object>
        <fx:Object data="40"></fx:Object>
    </s:ArrayList>
</s:SpinnerList>
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole purpose of a SpinnerList is to keep repeating.  IF you don't want it to repeat, then use a regular [List](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc2368ca491e3ff923c946c5112135c8ee9e-7fff.html).  The regular list does have a mobile optimized skin.